# Mapping a m:n relationship twice

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I am wondering if it is possible to map a m:n relationship in the database twice in a EF4 Model.

Consider this database model:

http://andarki.dk/stackoverflow/db.png

It is a standard m:n relationship between companies and users.
If the field works_at.is_locked_out is ignored during model generation it generates a nice * to * relationship in EF:

http://andarki.dk/stackoverflow/pretty.png

If i enable works_at.is_locked_out it looks more like the original db schema:

http://andarki.dk/stackoverflow/detailed.png

Is it possible to have both relations at once?
For some queries works_at.is_locked_out isn't necessary and having the direct link makes it easier to query in those cases.
When i add both relations i get the error

```
Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 23, 30:Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.
TestModel.edml
```

Is this in any way possible or is it a case of me trying to have my cake and eating it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both at the same time is not possible as you see with the error you are presented. [This article by Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/inserting-many-to-many-relationships-in-ef-with-or-without-a-join-entity/) will explain a lot, if not all. And I think you should go for alternative 2, because as you said it **isn't always** necessary, but sometimes (or in the near future) it is. That field isn't there without any purpose I guess... ;) Good luck!